# How to use IIf function inside IN Clause?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure as under

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_testProc]
    (@Product NVARCHAR(200) = '', 
     @BOMBucket NVARCHAR(100) = '')
    --exec usp_testProc '','1'
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Mytbl x
    WHERE 1 = 1
      AND (@Product IS NULL OR @Product = '' OR x.PRODUCT = @Product)
      AND (@BOMBucket IS NULL OR @BOMBucket = '' OR CAST(x.BOMBucket AS NVARCHAR(100)) IN (IIF(@BOMBucket != '12+', @BOMBucket, '13,14')))
END
```

Everything else if working fine except when I am passing the bucket value as 12+ . It should ideally show the result for bucket 13 and 14. But the result set is blank.

I know IN expects values as ('13','14'). But somehow not able to fit it in the program.

Comment: `Mytbl.BOMBucket` is an `integer`?

Comment: yes it is integer.

Comment: `IN` matches one value in a list of values. That you try to do doesn't have a *list* of values, it returns only a *single* value each time. Either the contents of `@BOMBucket` or the string `'13,14'`. Essentially, it's the same as `( (@BOMBucket !='12+ AND BOMBucker=@BOMBucket( OR (BOMBucket='13,14')`

Comment: Using such catch-all queries results in code that's hard to read *and* produces inefficient execution plans. If you don't want to use the `@Product` parameter, just *don't* use it in the query at all. You gain nothing by creating such a query inside a stored procedure. It's neither safer nor faster.

Comment: Furthermore, `CAST(x.BOMBucket AS NVARCHAR(100))` prevents the server from using any indexes that cover BOMBucket, resulting in a full table scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express that logic in a Boolean expression.

```
...
(@BOMBucket <> '12+'
 AND cast(x.BOMBucket AS nvarchar(100)) = @BOMBucket
  OR @BOMBucket = '12+'
     AND cast(x.BOMBucket AS nvarchar(100)) IN ('13', '14'))
...
```

But casting the column prevents indexes from being used. You rather should cast the other operand. Like in:

```
x.BOMBucket = cast(@BOMBucket AS integer)
```

But then you had the problem, that the input must not be a string representing an inter but can be any string. this would cause an error when casting. In newer SQL Server versions you could circumvent that by using [`try_cast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but not in 2012 as far as I know. Maybe you should rethink your approach overall and pass a table variable with the wanted `BOMBucket` as integers instead.